# Solving a linear system whose coefficient matrix is dense but symmetric

Tags: linear-solver, linear-system, dense-matrix

For solving a linear system,

$Ax = b$.

If $A$ is a dense but symmetric $n \times n$ matrix, how much memory is required?

$A$ is symmetric, which means only the upper (or lower) triangular part of $n \times (n+1)/2$ entries would be necessary. Does $A$'s memory requirement have to be 8 bytes $\times n \times n$ or can it be lowered toward 8 bytes $\times n \times (n+1)/2$?

Comment: Specifically, you will want to look up the difference between a regular LU decomposition and the Cholesky decomposition that exploits the symmetry of the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be lowered; it is called [packed storage](https://netlib.org/lapack/lug/node123.html) and Lapack has some functions to deal with it, e.g., [`?PPSVX`](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/de/d49/group__double_o_t_h_e_rsolve_gaf53874c0cb1724d22aa2e3ede6b64ac1.html), [`?SPSVX`](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html-3.6.1/dd/d4a/dspsvx_8f_adc9982047997c5afe340185be14abd25.html).

As this storage scheme is somewhat uncommon, I don't think you can use it easily in higher-level packages such as Matlab or Scipy. There is a [Julia package](https://github.com/JaneliaSciComp/SymmetricFormats.jl) though.

Alternatively, if you have an upper and a lower triangular matrix with known diagonal, such as the results of an LU factorization, you can pack two in the space of one $n\times n$ array.

Comment: A small word of caution is that these packed storage routines are slower than the corresponding non-packed ones, as they rely on BLAS-1 routines instead of BLAS-2 or BLAS-3. You might also look into "rectangular packed format", which can achieve BLAS-3 performance without using duplicate storage (though this is easier for some kernels than others).